# How to prevent component to re-render every time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I have a custom component where I want to prevent the `useEffect` to fire every time the component is rendering.

The main idea is to get the font-family name from the API and then pass it to the style value, so I want to get the font family just once - not every time the component renders in other screens.

Here's what I tried, but it doesn't work as expected, it's not updating the state after getting the value from API (`getValue()` not called).

```
import React, {useCallback, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';
import {Text, StyleSheet, Platform} from 'react-native';
import {COLORS} from '../../common';

const AppText = ({children, style, ...rest}) => {
  const isMounted = useRef(false);
  const [fontFamily, setFontFamily] = useState('Helvetica-Bold');

  const getValue = useCallback(() => {
    // mock API 
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('AppText: get font family name from API!!');
      setFontFamily('HelveticaNeue');
    }, 200);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted.current) {
      getValue();
    } else {
      isMounted.current = true;
      return;
    }
  }, [getValue]);

  return (
    <Text
      style={[
        styles.text,
        style,
        {
          fontFamily: fontFamily,
        },
      ]}
      {...rest}>
      {children}
    </Text>
  );
};

export {AppText};
```

using:

```
Home/About/etc // other screens


const Home = () => {
   return(
     <View>
        <AppText> Hey from home </AppText>
    </View>
   );
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, in `useEffect` you have to pass an actual state variable you want to watch, and not the name of the function that will eventually change the state. So if you want to "watch" changes in the font you pass `[fontFamily]`

Comment: it doesn't call `getValue` because of `isMounted=false` if that's problem

Comment: @Kokodoko I think his problem is that he only wants to call the useEffect once globally. (at least _not every time the component renders in other screens_ ) this is what I understand.     You can get rid of the useCallback and inline the function to useEffect if you leave the dependency array empty. This would result in the function being called once for each mounted component. If you just want it once globally either create a function outside the component (than it will be called upon importing once) or push it up the tree to a higher component (e.g. your Home or App) and use a context

Comment: @Kilian exactly that's what i need, I'm using redux for app settings if I get the font name from the store and pass it in the component itself maybe this case hit performance or? because as I thought there were no other cases to get the value (tree, component 'as I thinking above ') and the Tree not a good idea in my case I have many screens.

Comment: Contexts were specifically created for this kind of task and can often replace redux. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html  . Fetching the value once at a higher component and passing it down is the react way to do it (either via props or context). An alternative would be to write a custom hook but if the values does not change this is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a context to propergate the value down into multiple components (or use props) and just fetch it once higher up in the tree.

```js
//App.js

import {useEffect, createContext, useState} from "react";

export const FontFamilyContext = createContext("DefaultFont");

const App = () =>{

  const [font,setFont] = useState();

  useEffect( () =>{
    setFont(loadFont());
  },[]);

  return (
    <FontFamilyContext.Provider value={font} >
      <Screen />
      <ScreenViaProp fontFamily={font} />
    </FontFamilyContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;


//Screen.jsx

//Advantage The font family can be used in nested components deep down

import { useContext } from "react";
import {FontContext} from "./App";

const Screen = () =>{

  const fontFamily = useContext(FontFamilyContext);

  return (
    <div style={{fontFamily: fontFamily}}>

    </div>
  )
}

// ScreenViaProp .jsx  Easier and no context is required

const ScreenViaProp = ({fontFamily}) =>{
  return (
    <div style={{fontFamily: fontFamily}}>

    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const DEFAULT_FONT_FAMILY = 'Helvetica-Bold';
const AppText = ({children, style, ...rest}) => {
  const [fontFamily, setFontFamily] = useState(DEFAULT_FONT_FAMILY);

  useEffect(() => {
    // mock API 
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('AppText: get font family name from API!!');
      const FETCHED_FONT_FAMILY = 'HelveticaNeue';
      if (FETCHED_FONT_FAMILY !== fontFamily) setFontFamily(FETCHED_FONT_FAMILY);
    }, 200);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Text
      style={[
        styles.text,
        style,
        {
          fontFamily: fontFamily,
        },
      ]}
      {...rest}>
      {children}
    </Text>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `custom hook` to load the font value only once in you app :

`customHooks.js`

```
let fontFromApi = null;

const fontP = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('get font family name from API!!');
    fontFromApi = 'HelveticaNeue';
    resolve(fontFromApi);
  }, 200);
});

export function useFont() {
  const [font, setFont] = useState(fontFromApi || "Helvetica-Bold");

  if (fontFromApi === null) {
    fontP.then(v => setFont(v));
  }
  
  return font;
}
```

I declared a custom hook called `useFont` returning the font from the API. If the font is not loaded yet, it will return the fallback value `Helvetica-Bold`.

`AppText.jsx`

```
const { useFont } from './customHooks'

const AppText = ({children, style, ...rest}) => {
  const fontFamily = useFont();

  return (
    <Text
      style={[
        styles.text,
        style,
        { fontFamily }
      ]}
      {...rest}>
      {children}
    </Text>
  );
};
```